# Como muestro una vista en laravel desde un controlador exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-7

Estuve intentando atrapar el mensaje de error 401, no autenticado, lo conseguí desde el app/Exceptions/Handler,php en la función render, pero requiero que me muestre una vista de error personalizada, tengo en mi carpeta errors ya una vista blade 401, pero cuando hago el return o redirect a la vista, me la muestra por consola y no en la página como puedo devolver la vista de manera normal, intente con una ruta web.php y llevarlo a un controlador pero no salio, la otra es redireccionar a mi url a /e401, tan solo mostrar la pagina, saben como?

App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    { 
        if($exception->getMessage() =='Unauthenticated.'){
            $msg = $exception->getMessage();
            return view('errors.401'); //Aqui quiero retornar la pagina de error pero no por consola
            
        }else{
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que simplemente podrías crear una ruta y agregarle un nombre para que se vea mejor y luego redirigir a dicha ruta cuando se encuentre unauthenticated

Ruta:

Route::get('mylogin', 'LoginController@showLogin')->name('login');

Redireccionamiento:

redirect()->guest(route('login'));